# Automatic version updating using git on commit

Tags: python, git, version-control, versioning

I have a python project I'm working on using git for version control I want to set up a unique version number for every commit based on [PEP440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/).

I.e I would use the following version numbering `N(.N)*[{a|b|rc}N][.postN][.devN]` for the master branch, were for every commit for which a higher level version number isn't incremented `devN` will be auto incremented by git on commit, the rest of the version would hopefully be controlled by a special git command: `git increment-version {level}`

where level would be one of `major`, `minor`, `patch`, `patch-{level}` (`patch` is the same as `patch-0`), `alpha`, `beta`, `release`, `final`, `post` would map to the version string as  `{major}[.{minor}[(.{patch-N})*]]`, `alpha => aN`, `beta => bN`, `release => rcN`, `post => postN`, with `beta` replacing `alpha` and `release` replacing `beta`, `final` removes pre-release component, if the earlier one is used than the current this should produce a error, When a higher level version is incremented all lower levels are rest to zero, and any patch level set to zero is not included in the string, incrementing `major`, `minor` or `patch` will set the per-release component to `a0`.

For a branch branching off of the master branch the same numbers will be used but the version applies to the branch it self, with the version string being

`{master_version}+{branch_name}.{branch_version}` where branch version undertakes the same format as for the master version

For branches off a non master branch the local version is extended as follows
`{branchN_name}.{branchN_version}(.{branchN_name}.{branchN_version})*`
where branch names must start with a letter and not match any of [{a|b|rc}N][.postN][.devN], each `{branchN_name}.{branchN_version}` is treated like a extended form of `.postN` component

The location of the version string should be specified as a file that is part of the repository, and a line pattern as follows using a string with escape sequences `\\ = \`, `\" = "`, `\' = '`, `\v = version string`
i.e. `"__version__ = \"\v\""`.

On a commit git should search the specified file for this line load the version string, update it and write out a new version string to the file, intermediately before committing the changes including the updated version string, if the file has be otherwise change, but not added to the commit, the version, string should be update, in the version from the previous commit, and this change propagated to the modified file. If a on the master branch, and a version number has be incremented by a call to `git increment-version {level}`
than git should also generate a tag for this commit matching the version string.

Ideally I would like to increment this extension to git by way of a python script that is part of the repository it self. However I'm open to other ways of solving this problem.

EDIT:

I believe the best solution is to make git command i.e. git-autoversion executable.

Then to enable said versioning for a repository I would run `git autoversion --init --style=pep440 --template=python-info --versionfile=XXX/_info.py`

which would create a file `.gitautoversion` which would contain

```
[autoversion]
version=1.0
local=
style=pep440
template=python-info
file=XXX/_info.py
```

it would also have a hook `git autoversion --commit` which should be run as a pre-commit hook.

finally it could be called as `git autoversion --[major|minor|patch{-level}|alpha|beta|release|final|post|dev]` which can be used to mark the version number to increment, only the last call would count this would add the line `increment=xxx` to the `.gitautoversion` configuration file, the command `git autoversion --commit` would read this and increment the version, if no increment is specified it defaults to dev, finally it invokes the command `git-autoversion-tpl-{template} --version={version} --local={local} --file={file}` to update the version file.

QUESTION: is their a way to install a global git hook when autoversion is installed to call `git autoversion --commit` for a commit to any repository this command can then check for `.gitautoversion` if found update the version otherwise do nothing. If not this would require manual installing of the hook.

QUESTION 2: is their a way to hook an extra argument to `git commit`, say `--autoversion=[major|minor|patch{-level}|alpha|beta|release|final|post|dev]`, which would invoke the autoversion command before running commit hooks?

Comment: Another solution to this would be to use editable installs, as you probably don't want to ship an sdist for every commit you push. You can then try and get the currently checked out git commit in the editable install, which changes its `__version__` attribute accordingly.

Comment: That's why the default git commit should increment devN number, this wouldn't imply a corresponding sdist, and tags are not generated for such commits, this would make the devN and local components internal book keeping parts of the version string. The idea is that each commit to master should represent at the very least an increment of the developmental version.

Comment: Standard way of doing this uses `git describe`, which works differently than your description

Comment: Just looked up `git describe`, it seams like a more basic features, i.e. requires manual management of all but development/build/commit number, by specify the tag manually, and it doesn't seam to have a way of writing say value to a file, which is important for embedding the unique version string in the code, I would say what I want could be considered as a generalization (i.e. provide a naming pattern) and extension (i.e. storing the value in a file as part of the commit, and automatic tag generation) of what `git describe` offers.

Comment: My suggestion is to use git tags and a pre-commit hook:  in the pre-commit hook, find all tags, check for any that match one of your 'increment' levels, delete those tags, then do the appropriate increment, save the version file, and add it to the commit.  so:  `git tag minor` before the commit would increment the minor version and whatever else is needed.

Comment: See also https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/141973/225719

Comment: @j-earls in regards to git hooks, how could I go about making a hook that would run on both windows and unix systems, reliably i.e. someway of specifying a command to be passed to the system shell, beyond a simple shebang i.e. tell git to do something like, pass `python $1 $*` to the system shell where $1 is the name of the script and S4 is any arguments to be passed to it. or a cross platform version of `/usr/bin/env`

Comment: @glenflet i assume that depends on your git installation on windows.  if you're uising git-bash, it also has `/bin/env` so both solutions can use a python script that has the shebang #!/bin/env python.  You could also write a "central" script to do the version management, and a platform-specific hook script to run that "central" script.  I've not done git hooks in windows, so I can't help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use `version_scheme` option in the following pypi project to do what you want

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools_scm